# I need to make multiple copies of google sheets, including sharing and permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have weekly, hour by hour production logs for many different machines. I need to make 52 copies at a time, keeping permissions intact. I did find a way to make copies, but I lose the permissions on the protected ranges.
This is how I made the copies-

```
function copyDocs() {
 for(i=0; i<52; i++){ 
  var drive=DriveApp.getFileById('Sheet ID');
  drive.makeCopy();
 }
}
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I also have same requirement.